# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/gallery_localizations.dart'

Tags: flutter

I am now using flutter gallary in my project, this is the package reference:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/gallery_localizations.dart';
```

but it shows:

```
Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/gallery_localizations.dart'.
```

I added lib in `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
intl: ^0.16.1
flutter_localized_locales: ^1.1.1
```

and added `l10n.yaml`:

```yaml
template-arb-file: intl_en.arb
output-localization-file: gallery_localizations.dart
output-class: GalleryLocalizations
preferred-supported-locales:
  - en
use-deferred-loading: false
```

Am I missing something? still not work, what should I do to make it work? This is the full code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:animations/animations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/gallery_localizations.dart';

enum BottomNavigationDemoType {
  withLabels,
  withoutLabels,
}

class BottomNavigationDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavigationDemo({Key key, @required this.type}) : super(key: key);

  final BottomNavigationDemoType type;

  @override
  _BottomNavigationDemoState createState() => _BottomNavigationDemoState();
}

class _BottomNavigationDemoState extends State<BottomNavigationDemo> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  String _title(BuildContext context) {
    switch (widget.type) {
      case BottomNavigationDemoType.withLabels:
        return GalleryLocalizations.of(context)
            .demoBottomNavigationPersistentLabels;
      case BottomNavigationDemoType.withoutLabels:
        return GalleryLocalizations.of(context)
            .demoBottomNavigationSelectedLabel;
    }
    return '';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final colorScheme = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
    final textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;

    var bottomNavigationBarItems = <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.add_comment),
        label: GalleryLocalizations.of(context).bottomNavigationCommentsTab,
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
        label: GalleryLocalizations.of(context).bottomNavigationCalendarTab,
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.account_circle),
        label: GalleryLocalizations.of(context).bottomNavigationAccountTab,
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.alarm_on),
        label: GalleryLocalizations.of(context).bottomNavigationAlarmTab,
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.camera_enhance),
        label: GalleryLocalizations.of(context).bottomNavigationCameraTab,
      ),
    ];

    if (widget.type == BottomNavigationDemoType.withLabels) {
      bottomNavigationBarItems = bottomNavigationBarItems.sublist(
          0, bottomNavigationBarItems.length - 2);
      _currentIndex =
          _currentIndex.clamp(0, bottomNavigationBarItems.length - 1).toInt();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(_title(context)),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: PageTransitionSwitcher(
          child: _NavigationDestinationView(
            // Adding [UniqueKey] to make sure the widget rebuilds when transitioning.
            key: UniqueKey(),
            item: bottomNavigationBarItems[_currentIndex],
          ),
          transitionBuilder: (child, animation, secondaryAnimation) {
            return FadeThroughTransition(
              child: child,
              animation: animation,
              secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        showUnselectedLabels:
        widget.type == BottomNavigationDemoType.withLabels,
        items: bottomNavigationBarItems,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedFontSize: textTheme.caption.fontSize,
        unselectedFontSize: textTheme.caption.fontSize,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
        selectedItemColor: colorScheme.onPrimary,
        unselectedItemColor: colorScheme.onPrimary.withOpacity(0.38),
        backgroundColor: colorScheme.primary,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _NavigationDestinationView extends StatelessWidget {
  _NavigationDestinationView({Key key, this.item}) : super(key: key);

  final BottomNavigationBarItem item;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        ExcludeSemantics(
          child: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/demos/bottom_navigation_background.png',
                  package: 'flutter_gallery_assets',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: IconTheme(
            data: const IconThemeData(
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 80,
            ),
            child: Semantics(
              label: GalleryLocalizations.of(context)
                  .bottomNavigationContentPlaceholder(
                item.label,
              ),
              child: item.icon,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

when I run the command `flutter clean && flutter run` , shows the result:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/AndroidStudioProjects/Cruise% flutter clean && flutter run 
Attempted to generate localizations code without having the flutter: generate flag turned on.
Check pubspec.yaml and ensure that flutter: generate: true has been added and rebuild the project. Otherwise, the localizations source code will not be
importable.
Generating synthetic localizations package has failed.
```

Comment: Do `flutter clean && flutter run`. It will work, I presume

Comment: `[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/AndroidStudioProjects/Cruise% flutter clean && flutter run 
Attempted to generate localizations code without having the flutter: generate flag turned on.
Check pubspec.yaml and ensure that flutter: generate: true has been added and rebuild the project. Otherwise, the localizations source code will not be
importable.
Generating synthetic localizations package has failed.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the imports working by adding these two lines to the pubspec.yaml file:

```
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3 
flutter_gallery: ^2.4.0+20400
```

The first line is actually replacing the original cupertino-icons dependency that is version 1.0.0 and the flutter gallery dependency requires a different version, that is 0.1.3.

Then update the imports with 'flutter pub get'

This site [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gallery/install) lists all of the possible flutter_gallery imports.

Comment: adding 
intl: ^0.17.0

to dependencies solved it for me

Answer (score 101):

I followed the Flutter official doc (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) but came across the same problem as you. I first tried "flutter upgrade". The issue still remained.

**After that, I tried to close my IDE(Android studio) and open it again, and the issue was cleared!**

Comment: I thought such problems can only be found in eclipse and not in intellij... but here we go... a restart helped.

Comment: Helped too for vscode

Comment: It should be accepted answer.

Comment: It is so sad that this really is the best answer. IMO the dart lint developers could have made a better job with this.

Comment: helped for IntelliJ Idea Ultimate Edition too (with flutter plugin)

Comment: Yes this helped for Android Studio. I'm guessing this is a linting issue as it doesn't throw any errors if you actually run the app.

Comment: i think you should **blod** the last sentence : )

Comment: This helped for vscode. This is the best answer.

Answer (score 71):

Additionally to @Sleepingisimportant answer's, you can restart "Dart Analysis Server" and the issue will be resolved.

[image: Restart Dart Analysis Server]

This button is in the Dart Analysis Tab here on Android Studio which I guess means it's also on Intelij.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! The file is there, but the Dart daemon is not clever enough to find it. Closing IDE and reopening works sometimes, this seem to work always.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 29):

If you are using a package `flutter_gen` you need to remove it from pubscpec.yaml to resolve conflict.

Comment: that's it Thanks

Comment: holy cow this was it....

Comment: That was my issue also. Basically the `intl` package generates localisation code under a fake `flutter_gen` package, but there is also a real `flutter_gen` package on pub.dev. If you install the latter, it will take priority and hide the generated localisation code, so it will appear to not exist.

Comment: oh my friend thank you so much you are life savior. thanks a lot

Comment: I had the same problem: just try to remove 'generate: true' in your pubspec.yaml and disable 'synthetic-package: false' in your l10n.yaml

Comment: that's it, after 30 mins try to restart my IDE.

Comment: thanks that helped, I created my app with community suggestions and ran `dart fix --apply` which seems to have broken it. Removing `flutter_gen` worked.

Comment: Crazy thing is I don't even recall why / how `flutter_gen` was added to my `pubspec`

Answer (score 28):

I just solved it after adding l10n.yaml, then did this:

1. restart your project
2. Run:

> flutter clean

> flutter pub get

Comment: man, that's helped me, better to do it first, before adding dependencies as in chosen answer

Comment: helped me too! dont get why flutter clean resolves this but anyway...

Comment: @Logemann Because it's a problem with the cash memory, it need just to be refreshed, that is because there is no perfect software even if it's from Google.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem, I just closed and opened my folder again, I'm using vs code.

Comment: I had this same issue with `import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart'` in Visual Studio Code, and after closing the window and reopening it, the error was gone.

Comment: this actually works for me

Comment: I close and open and works but after sometime or some changes the error is back again

Comment: Does not work if you do not have l10n.yaml file inside project folder and generate: true inside pubscpec.yaml. It just wastes time and all errors show up again after editor finishes indexing project files.

Comment: Cheerio! This is a faster way when compared to restarting Android Studio. Thank you very much... :)

Answer (score 21):

View > Command Palette and then typing Dart: Restart Analysis Server.

Answer (score 12):

I solved it by running on the terminal in the main folder:

```
flutter gen-l10n
```

Answer (score 8):

Try to run `flutter update-packages` in `~/flutter/packages/flutter`.

```
flutter update-packages
```

Or update the Flutter SDK by using the `flutter upgrade` command:

```
flutter upgrade
```

This command gets the most recent version of the Flutter SDK that’s available on your current Flutter channel.

More information on how to upgrad the Flutter SDK or switching Flutter channels : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading

This will fix your `import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/gallery_localizations.dart';` issue.

Answer (score 7):

At the bottom of our pubspec.yaml you should set generate to true...

```
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true
```

Comment: This was the solution for me :) Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue and what I did was I ran `flutter clean` command first in the terminal. After that I ran the flutter by `flutter run` command again. It worked.

Answer (score 5):

for those who inherit the project from some others, please run below before any other trial:

```
flutter gen-l10n
```

Answer (score 3):

`flutter pub get` could also help if this has not already been done. This is important after adding new stuff to pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 3):

I followed the flutter documentations [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) to resolve the issue:

*To use flutter_localizations, add the package as a dependency to your `pubspec.yaml` file:*

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations: # Add this line
    sdk: flutter         # Add this line
```

*Next, run pub get packages, then import the flutter_localizations library:*

```
 import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
```

**The next part is critical in removing the error:**

*Once the flutter_localizations package is added, use the following instructions to add localized text to your application.*

*Add the intl package to the `pubspec.yaml` file:*

```
  dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      flutter_localizations:
        sdk: flutter
      intl: ^0.17.0 # Add this line
```

*Also, in the pubspec.yaml file, enable the generate flag. This is added to the section of the pubspec that is specific to Flutter, and usually comes later in the pubspec file.*

*# The following section is specific to Flutter.*

```
flutter:
  generate: true # Add this line
```

Add a new `yaml` file to the root directory of the Flutter project called `l10n.yaml` with the following content:

```
arb-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: app_en.arb
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart
```

This file configures the localization tool; in this example, the input files are located in *${FLUTTER_PROJECT}/lib/l10n*, the `app_en.arb` file provides the template, and the generated localizations are placed in the `app_localizations.dart` file.

In `${FLUTTER_PROJECT}/lib/l10n`, add the `app_en.arb` template file.

*Next, add an `app_es.arb` file in the same directory for Spanish translation of the same message:*

*Now, run your app so that codegen takes place. You should see generated files in:* `${FLUTTER_PROJECT}/.dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n.`

*Add the import statement on `app_localizations.dart`.*

```
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'r using VSCode,
simply click **"Shift+CMD+P"** then **"Dart: Restart Analysis Server"**

[image: Dart: Restart Analysis Server]

Answer (score 2):

Adding my contribution here, as none of the answers worked for me. I went through the documentation and found that I need to run the following command for code generation to take place. Run `flutter clean` and then run

```
flutter gen-l10n
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions above worked! Except for the one answered by Abdouly M.
Just run

```
flutter gen-l10n
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to **close and reopen your IDE** so it re-analyses your code base. VS Code in particular sometimes doesn't recognise changes to the code base but closing and reopening your IDE will trigger a re-index / analysis of your code and should resolve this phantom error.

Answer (score 1):

Add new line at every arb files. E.g. into l10n/app_en.arb. Then click Pub get.

Answer (score 1):

Please add generate: true in the bottom of flutter section. After that. Restart your editor or IDE tool. Run flutter clean and flutter pub get.

```
environment:
dependencies:
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all,
Please try to create flutter project like this :

```
flutter create -t skeleton -a java -i swift --org com.meraj your_app_name
```

Then use 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart'.
After this process, if you face the same problem then close your editor and open again.
If this process don't work, then write a command:

```
flutter clean
```

And then write:

```
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 1):

sometimes the issue is not about class AppLocalization, the issue is that **your IDE can't build synthetic packages from generated folders** for some reason, you can **generate code inside your l10n folder** and use it like a handwritten class.
How to do that:

1. go to your l10n.yaml
2. add `synthetic-package: false` line into file.

This way code will be generated into your lib/l10n or whatever you have as arb-dir and IDE will not have any issues, this goes with every code generated lib that rely on synthetics

Answer (score 1):

i just remove this line `flutter_gen` in `pubspec.yaml` then run `flutter gen-l10n` and it work

Answer (score 0):

If someone open existing project with Localisation already added.
This error always comes.
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart'; not exist

So run this command in terminal :
flutter pub add flutter_gen

Answer (score 0):

`Flutter clean` or restarting editor, Android Studio won't solve the issue. You need to have l10n.yaml file inside project folder. You probably faced with this issue after creating new project and copy-pasting content from another project. Inside of l10n.yaml file is like this:

```
arb-dir: lib/src/localization
template-arb-file: app_en.arb
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart
```

And add this line into pubspec.yaml:

```
  # Enable generation of localized Strings from arb files.
  generate: true
```

[More details here](https://medium.com/@echolaojue/how-to-make-l10n-with-flutter-fd61e21e61d8)

Answer (score 0):

```
Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart'.
```

I've had the same issue, and I'm using VSCode, all I did was restart the IDE and the error gone.

Answer (score 0):

flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter pub run phrase
flutter pub run intl_utils:generate

It helped me, you can try it too

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me after upgrading to Flutter 3.13.1.

I already had

```
flutter:
  generate: true
```

in my place.

I solved by removing the version number from intl package, so it can get the latest intl package.

Answer (score 0):

```
 flutter packages get
```

Then wait some seconds to apply the changes.

If that does not work, try

```
 flutter clean
 flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "generate: true" line to your pubspec.yaml file :

```
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
```

flutter:
**generate: true**

Answer (score 0):

with flutter SDK 3.13.9.

flutter gen-l10n should be done after flutter pub get

after flutterpub run ... error is displayed

i try to run apk in debug and the error is removed from file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

TRDL: rm pubspec.lock

after update flutter from 3.13.3 to 3.13.9
in macOS 14.1.2
and Xcode 15.0.1

got the same error:

> Could not build the precompiled application for the device. Error
> (Xcode): lib/main.dart:12:8: Error: Error when reading
> '../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-2.24.0/lib/firebase_core.dart':
> No such file or directory

the solution was:

1. delete on project folder: rm pubspec.lock
2. remove the pubget cache folder: rm -rf ~/.pub-cache/
3. clean your project: flutter clean
4. rebuild your project

also:

- no need add 'synthetic-package: false line' into l10n.yaml file.

just have in pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  generate: true
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the following to your `pubspec.yml`

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: any
```

2. In the `pubspec.yaml` file enable the generate flag

```
flutter:
  generate: true # Add this line
```

3. Create a **`l10n.yaml`** file at the root of your project include following content :

```
arb-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: app_en.arb
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart
nullable-getter: false # Optional line
```

*Adapt the code above to your project and naming*

4. Run `flutter clean && flutter pub get`