# Error setting-up flutter_localizations package "Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart'."

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

This error appears when I try to add language support to my flutter application:

```
Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart'. Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.
```

I’m using `flutter_localizations`, the project is built with dart 2.7.0

It seems that `flutter_localizations` needs latest sdk which is dart 2.13.0

How can I fix this?

Comment: And the solution in my case was this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69806283/422752

Answer (score 20):

I had this same issue with `import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart'` in Visual Studio Code after updating to Flutter 2.5.

After closing the VS Code window and reopening it, the error was gone.
If that doesn't work, try closing and opening VS Code again.

Or restart the Dart Analysis Server by going to **View > Command Palette** and then typing **Dart: Restart Analysis Server**.

Credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68150402/4797855 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/68731436/4797855.

Comment: `Dart: Restart Analysis Server.` It works! thanks

Answer (score 5):

Just type in the project terminal `flutter gen-l10n` it will solve your problem.

Comment: This works on my case. I'm using VSCode.

Answer (score 3):

Open Command Palette  and select **Dart: Restart Analysis Server.**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The solution in my case:
"If you are using a package flutter_gen you need to remove it from pubscpec.yaml to resolve conflict." credit [Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/gallery_localizations.dart'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64574620/target-of-uri-doesnt-exist-packageflutter-gen-gen-l10n-gallery-localizations/69806283#69806283)

Comment: Thanks @giorgio79.  That was the issue for me. In my case, I added `flutter_gen` package to the `dependencies` instead of adding `flutter_gen_runner` to `dev_dependencies`.

Answer (score 2):

Also, in the pubspec.yaml file, enable the generate flag. This is added to the section of the pubspec that is specific to Flutter, and usually comes later in the pubspec file.

```
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  generate: true # Add this line
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before, and I tried to solve it by adding charts_flutter to my pubspec.yaml but it didn't solve my.

Lucky me, charting library recently released a new version which is compatible with flutter 2.5. I didn't need to add anything to my pubspec(I removed chart_flutter from my ). just run the app even if the compiler shows an error saying Target of URI doesn't exist for the import line. The system is going to generate that file on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that there's an **l10n.yaml** file in your project root as follows.

## Example

### Demonstration variables

`foldername =` **l10n**
`defaultIntlFile =` **intl_en.arb**
`importFileName =` **app_localizations.dart**

### Import

`import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/`**importFileName**`'`;

### l10n.yaml

`arb-dir: lib/`**foldername**
`template-arb-file:` **intl_en.arb**
`output-localization-file:` **app_localizations.dart**

### Structure

`lib/`**foldername**`/`**defaultIntlFile**

Answer (score -1):

Just in your terminal run this command:

`flutter pub add flutter_gen/gen_l10n`

It fixed my app