# Flutter/ Android Studio: error: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart'

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Android Studio Bumblebee

```
| 2021.1.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8193401, built on February 17, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.3
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.bloc.intellij_generator_plugin (3.3.0), Dart (211.7811), org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.10-release-923-AS7442.40), io.flutter (65.2.2), org.intellij.plugins.markdown (211.7142.37)
```

flutter --version

```
Flutter 2.10.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision c860cba910 (10 days ago) • 2022-03-25 00:23:12 -0500
Engine • revision 57d3bac3dd
Tools • Dart 2.16.2 • DevTools 2.9.2
```

[Localization](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#using-the-dart-intl-tools)

pubspec.yaml

```
...
  flutter_gen: ^4.1.6
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.17.0


flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true
...
```

l10n.yaml(in project root):

```
arb-dir: lib/l10n/arb
template-arb-file: app_en.arb
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart
nullable-getter: false
```

Trying to import:

```
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
```

But get error:

```
error: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart'
```

Non of the following SO worked:

[one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67789828/error-setting-up-flutter-localizations-package-target-of-uri-doesnt-exist-pa)

[two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64574620/target-of-uri-doesnt-exist-packageflutter-gen-gen-l10n-gallery-localizations/68150402#68150402)

Comment: Have you defined the `l10n.yaml` for your project as mentioned [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10e0saTfAv32OZLRmONy866vnaw0I2jwL8zukykpgWBc/edit#heading=h.upcu5w85cvc2)?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the intl plugin in your code editor (Android Studio) then you should have this generated folder (lib/generated/l10n.dart).

Run this command in your terminal ' flutter pub run intl_utils:generate'

At check pubspec.yaml file,

```
    dependencies:
    
    flutter:
        sdk: flutter
    flutter_localizations:
        sdk: flutter
    intl_utils: ^2.6.1

flutter_intl:
  enabled: true
```

Then after it will be work, please try it.